# How to overwrite multiple versions of the same module via fragments?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm trying to overwrite a jsp from a LR 7 module, in the bnd.bnd file of the fragment module you have to provide the version:

```
Fragment-Host: com.liferay.announcements.web;bundle-version="1.0.6"
```

Let's assume this version is only supported for example in CE GA3, so what will happen if on CE GA2 or GA4 the bundle-version needs to be different to make it work or should i create multiple fragments modules projects in order to support different original module version ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking if you can override more than one version of a bundle with the same fragment? I don't think you can, but even if you could, you shouldn't.

From the Liferay Docs on [overriding a module's JSPs](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-a-modules-jsps):

> Supplying a specific host module version is important. If that version
>   of the module isn’t present, your fragment won’t attach itself to a
>   host, and that’s a good thing. A new version of the host module might
>   have changed its JSPs, so if your now-incompatible version of the JSP
>   is applied to the host module, you’ll break the functionality of the
>   host. It’s better to detach your fragment and leave it lonely in the
>   OSGi runtime than it is to break the functionality of an entire
>   application.

Comment: yeah i was wondered because on Liferay 6.2, with the same sdk you were able to support different versions